# modifying scipy stats.probplot plotting function with matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, scipy

I am not am expert with matplotlib, so I am having a hard time trying to set the parameters of scipy stats.

My code takes a pandas df column, iterates over the columns, and attempts to plot the values of the columns using the stats.probplot function. This is my code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
for col in model_predictions.columns:
    res = stats.probplot(df[col]), plot=plt)
    plt.legend = col
plt.show()
```

This generates the charts I want, but difficult to read (no legends, sames colors). Aside from plotting them on top of each other, I would like to plot each line in a different color, as well as add a legend for each line equal to the str in col. Any way to do this?

I can always take the tuple output of the function, run it by another new def, and add the outputs to a new pandas df (to later plot with more control); but I was wondering if there is a quicker way.

Thanks

Comment: Create a figure and axes outside of the loop and pass in the axes as the argument for `plot` should get them all on the same axes

Comment: The example in the [scipy.stats.probplot](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.probplot.html) docs actually shows how to use different subplots.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to use different subplots. I dont want different subplots, but all in the same plot.

Comment: put the `plt.show` outside the loop

Comment: Well, yes, what's the difference between using a single subplot, or multiple subplots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot them manually by taking the output of `stats.probplot`, i.e.:

```
from scipy.stats import probplot

for col in model_predictions.columns
    plt.plot(*stats.probplot(df[col])[0], label=col)
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This one almost works: plt.legend(loc='best') shows "TypeError: 'str' object is not callable"

Comment: Fixed it. Thank you @Mstaino